# Advanced Integer slicing when slicing object is an ndarray tuple

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, numpy-indexing

I understand how

```
x=np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] 
y = x[[0,1,2], [0,1,0]]
```

Output gives `y= [1  4  5]` This just takes the first list as rows and seconds list and columns.

But how does the the below work?

```
x = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],[ 3,  4,  5],[ 6,  7,  8],[ 9, 10, 11]]) 

rows = np.array([[0,0],[3,3]])
cols = np.array([[0,2],[0,2]]) 
y = x[rows,cols]
```

This gives the output of :

```
[[ 0  2]                                                                      
 [ 9 11]]
```

Can you please explain the logic when using ndarrays as slicing object? Why does it have a 2d array for both rows and columns. How are the rules different when the slicing object is a ndarray as opposed to a python list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've the following array `x`

```
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

And the indices `[0, 1, 2]` and `[0, 1, 0]` which when indexed into `x` like

```
x[[0,1,2], [0,1,0]]
```

gives

```
[1,  4,  5]
```

The indices that we used basically translates to:

```
[0, 1, 2] & [0, 1, 0] --> [0,0], [1,1], [2,0]
```

Since we used *1D list* as indices, we get 1D array as result.

---

With that knowledge, let's see the next case. Now, we've the array `x` as:

```
x = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],[ 3,  4,  5],[ 6,  7,  8],[ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Now the indices are 2D arrays.

```
rows = np.array([[0,0],[3,3]])
cols = np.array([[0,2],[0,2]])
```

This when indexed into the array `x` like:

```
x[rows,cols]
```

simply translates to:

```
[[0,0],[3,3]]
  | |   | |      ====> [[0,0]], [[0,2]], [[3,0]], [[3,2]]
[[0,2],[0,2]]
```

Now, it's easy to observe how these 4 `list of list` when indexed into the array `x` would give the following result (i.e. here it simply returns the *corner elements* from our array `x`):

```
[[ 0,  2]                                                                      
 [ 9, 11]]
```

Note that in this case we get the result as a 2D array (as opposed to 1D array in the first case) since our indices `rows` & `columns` itself were 2D arrays (i.e. equivalently `list of list`) whereas in the first case our indices were 1D arrays (or equivalently simple `list` without any nesting).

So, if you need 2D arrays as result, you need to give 2D arrays as indices.

Comment: Thanks! You just made my life easier by explaining x[rows, cols] in layman terms.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to wrap one's head around this is the following observation: The shape of the output is determined by the shape of the index array, or more precisely the shape resulting from broadcasting all the index arrays together.

Look at it like that: you have an array `A` of a given shape and another array `V` of some other shape and you want to fill `A` with values from `V`. What do you need to specify? Well, for each position in `A` you need to specify coordinates of some element in `V`. Therefore if `V` is ND you need N index arrays of the same shape as `A` or at least broadcastable to that. Then you index `V` by putting these index arrays at their coordinate positions in the `[]` expression.

Answer (score 1):

To stay simple, we'll stay 2D and assume `rows.shape` = `cols.shape`.  (You can break this rule with broadcasting, but for now we won't).  We'll call this shape `(I, J)`

then `y = x[rows, cols]` is the same as:

```
y = np.empty((I, J))
for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        y[i, j] = x[rows[i, j], cols[i, j]]
```